# How to hide default value with v-model and input fields?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input field with a v-model setting a variable in data:

```
  <div class="resource-cost--mat-one">
    <h3>Material 1</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="text" v-model="matOneCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--mat-two">
    <h3>Material 2</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="text" v-model="matTwoCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--mat-three">
    <h3>Material 3</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="text" v-model="matThreeCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--total">
    <h4>Total</h4>
    <p>{{ totalCost() }}</p>
  </div>
```

and

```
  data() {
    return {
      matOneCost: 0,
      matTwoCost: 0,
      matThreeCost: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
      totalCost() {
        let totalCost = parseInt(this.matOneCost) + parseInt(this.matTwoCost) + parseInt(this.matThreeCost)
        return totalCost;
      }
  }
```

By default, the input field has a value of 0 which I have to delete and type the value I actually want to input.

I've tried setting the data value to a string, which does get rid of the default value, however, until every  field has data, it returns NaN.

I also tried using the following for the output:

```
<p>{{ totalCost() || 0 }}</p>
```

which also works, until I start to input a number, and it'll output NaN again until all 3 are filled.

Behind the scenes, I just want the default value of 0 so that one or two fields can be filled and calculated without the 3rd field and without it automagically filling in the input field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition when you compute each property and use computed property instead of method :

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      matOneCost: 0,
      matTwoCost: 0,
      matThreeCost: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totalCost() {
      let totalCost = +(this.matOneCost || 0) + (+this.matTwoCost || 0) + (+this.matThreeCost || 0)
      return totalCost;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="resource-cost--mat-one">
    <h3>Material 1</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="number" v-model="matOneCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--mat-two">
    <h3>Material 2</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="number" v-model="matTwoCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--mat-three">
    <h3>Material 3</h3>
    <label>Cost <span>(per KG.)</span></label>
    <input class="" type="number" v-model="matThreeCost">
  </div>

  <div class="resource-cost--total">
    <h4>Total</h4>
    <p>{{ totalCost }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great for the default value being zero, but the input fields still have a zero in them by default.... Any idea how I can remove it?  Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, you could just init the bound properties by empty strings `''`

Comment: Ahh yes, duh.  Thank you so much for your help :D